# Calculate line integral in a vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem, curl

I have the following problem and I'm not able to solve it.
Given $F(x,y,z) = (1-2z, 0, 2y)$, calculate the line integral of C, where C is the contour of the surface. $S=\{(x,y,z) / x\geq 0,  y \geq 0, z\geq 0, z=1-x^2 - y^2\}$

Using Stokes Theorem:

$$\int _S \nabla x F\cdot dS = \int_C F\cdot dS $$

I have calculated the Curl $\nabla x F = (2,-2,0)$
I also parametrized the surface with $T(u,v)=(u,v,1-u^2-v^2)$
So my normal vector is $T_u x T_v=(2u,2v,1)$
$$\int_CF\cdot dS=\int _S \nabla x F\cdot dS =\int_0^1\int_0^1 (4u-4v)dudv=0$$

But C is a closed curve!! So if the line integral over a closed curve is cero, by the conservative vector field theorem, the curl of the field should ALSO be cero!! WTF, is going on? PLEASE HELP.

Comment: What makes you think $F$ is a conservative vector field?

Comment: Does the integral vanish over _every_ closed curve, or just this particular one?

Comment: Boots. The conservative vector field says all of the following are equivalent:
i) The line integral over a closed curve is zero   
ii) The line integral from A to B is the same, no matter the curve you take   
iii) $\nabla x F =0$  
iv) it exist a potential function f such that $\nabla f = F$

Comment: amd - It vanish over this particular curve that I know. I haven't checked for EVERY particular curve.

Comment: I got it, it does vanish over this particular curve, that doens't mean it vanish for EVERY curve. What a moron, thanks amd, I freaking love you.